# Keeping selected option while updating the text with HTMX

Tags: htmx

I have a form with select-options that I would like to translate between languages. The user can select an option before picking the language. I'm trying to update the options by passing a response from my backend to HTMX, but have not been able to keep the selected option.

Original select in page:

```
<select id="animal">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value"dog">Dog</option>
</select>
```

Translated select in response:

```
<select id="animal">
    <option value="cat">Katze</option>
    <option value"dog">Hund</option>
</select>
```

Can HTMX merge the new values into the existing DOM without loosing the current selection state?

I have tried with hx-preserve, but it does not work here since it also preserves the text that I would like to translate. I have also experimented with hx-swap-oob, but I couldn't make it work.

It can be handled by the backend, but it seems unnecessary so maybe it is possible to avoid? It would be nice and easy to return a translated version of the entire form without any request processing. The translations are static, so it seems reasonable to return them in a static response.

Comment: It seems reasonable to have it handled by the backend as the pre-selection is part of the state and should be passed by the url.